# ManyToMany relationships (Every category needs to has its own unique features(Booleanfield) for items)

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Basically, I`m working on a software catalog, which will have software categories(for example Accounting Software, Payroll Software, Data Visualisation Software, etc.) And of course, there will be some software items in these categories.

Each category has its own unique features.

For instance, Accounting software has:
- Accounts payable
- Expense Tracking
- Billing & Invoicing etc.

These features will be boolean fields. The reason is showing all the features in the software item page as 'pros and cons'. *(For better UX)*.

I have created a software category models and software item models with **m2m** relations. Now I want to add new features to my categories and show them in my software items page. But each feature (boolean fields) **should be unique (True or False)** for the software item.

Sorry for my basic English. But I hope you can understand the problem.

I have tried to add the through model for my m2m relation. But it is not handy and I believe there must be a much more elegant way than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the same kind of cases, I`m sharing a very useful **blog post from Vitor Freitas.**

With the help of some ajax codes, you can handle it really easily.

Good luck fellas.

[How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an intermediate model to store all the extra fields. You can do so by using the "through" argument on a ManytoManyField.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Yes, I have tried through models. But it is not handy in my case. I need every category has its own unique options and when you gonna add the item to the category, unique options should be appear as boolean fields in forms.